# Read XML to linq object, then create XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pp010 xmlns="http://www.123456768.com/technology">
    <rptHdr>
        <exchNam>MyXML</exchNam>
        <envText>P</envText>
        <rptCod>pp010</rptCod>
        <rptNam>Daily Stock</rptNam>
        <membLglNam>CompanyA</membLglNam>
        <rptPrntEffDat>2015-04-14</rptPrntEffDat>
        <rptPrntRunDat>2015-04-14</rptPrntRunDat>
    </rptHdr>
    <pp010Grp>
        <pp010KeyGrp>
            <membClgIdCod>HBGKP</membClgIdCod>
        </pp010KeyGrp>
        <pp010Grp1>
            <pp010KeyGrp1>
                <membExchIdCod>JBGJG</membExchIdCod>
            </pp010KeyGrp1>
            <pp010Grp2>
                <pp010KeyGrp2>
                    <currTypCod>CHF</currTypCod>
                </pp010KeyGrp2>
                <pp010Grp3>
                    <pp010KeyGrp3>
                        <acctTypGrp>PP</acctTypGrp>
                    </pp010KeyGrp3>
                    <pp010Rec>
                        <mgnGrpCod>     </mgnGrpCod>
                        <mgnClsCod>CSLN </mgnClsCod>
                        <mgnPremiumAmnt>+222926.00</mgnPremiumAmnt>
                        <mgnLiqDlvAmnt>+0.00</mgnLiqDlvAmnt>
                        <mgnSprdAmnt>+0.00</mgnSprdAmnt>
                        <mgnAddlAmnt>+89349.30</mgnAddlAmnt>
                        <unadjMgnReq>+312275.30</unadjMgnReq>
                    </pp010Rec>
                    <pp010Rec>
                        <mgnGrpCod>     </mgnGrpCod>
                        <mgnClsCod>CSLM </mgnClsCod>
                        <mgnPremiumAmnt>+55112.00</mgnPremiumAmnt>
                        <mgnLiqDlvAmnt>+0.00</mgnLiqDlvAmnt>
                        <mgnSprdAmnt>+0.00</mgnSprdAmnt>
                        <mgnAddlAmnt>+30854.40</mgnAddlAmnt>
                        <unadjMgnReq>+85966.40</unadjMgnReq>
                    </pp010Rec>
```

I am using the following code but cannot seem to create an `IEnumerable` with the data from `<pp010Rec>... </pp010Rec>`

```
public class MarginRep
{
    public string mgnGrpCod { get; set; }
    public string mgnClsCod { get; set; }
    public string mgnPremiumAmnt { get; set; }
    public string mgnLiqDlvAmnt { get; set; }
    public string mgnSprdAmnt { get; set; }
    public string mgnAddlAmnt { get; set; }
    public string unadjMgnReq { get; set; }
}

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string file =    @"D:\WorkDesktop\VisualStudio\file.xml";

     XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(file);

     IEnumerable<MarginRep> myMarginRep = 
         from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("pp010Rec")
         select new MarginRep()
                {
                    mgnGrpCod = (string)c.Attribute("mgnGrpCod"),
                    mgnClsCod = (string)c.Attribute("mgnClsCod"),
                    mgnPremiumAmnt = (string)c.Attribute("mgnPremiumAmnt"),
                    mgnLiqDlvAmnt = (string)c.Attribute("mgnLiqDlvAmnt"),
                    mgnSprdAmnt = (string)c.Attribute("mgnSprdAmnt"),
                    mgnAddlAmnt = (string)c.Attribute("mgnAddlAmnt"),
                    unadjMgnReq = (string)c.Attribute("unadjMgnReq"),
                };
    }
```

Sorry for the large amount of the XML. I felt I needed to display it as the first couple of lines I don't need and cannot seem to navigate down the `<pp010Rec>`.

IF you can offer any help I would be grateful, if you can point me into the direction literature I can spend time reading and try it alone.

Cheers,

Comment: What do you mean by saying that you cannot create IEnumerable? Do you get an error? If so - what error. Do you get unexpected result? If so - what is the expected result and what you are actually getting?

Comment: Your XML is broken. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)

Comment: Thanks Eminem, No Errors were found. I didnt post the last lines of the XML above to keep it short.

Comment: dotnetom. no errors. i just dont see an object populated with those fields when i debug

Comment: Im a newbie with Linq so please accept my apologies...

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want the values not the attributes, so change:

```
  mgnGrpCod = (string)c.Attribute("mgnGrpCod"),
```

To:

```
  mgnGrpCod = (string)c.Element("mgnGrpCod").Value,
```

Do the same with the other properties

Comment: Isn't his xml syntax's broken? I've tested it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) and it reports a problem.

Comment: I guess you're right, I just tested the "pp010Rec" elements and deleted everything else.

Comment: Missing closing tag, perhaps he only pasted part of the xml

Comment: Yes, only part of the XML. not the closing tags

Answer (score 2):

I a bit changed .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pp010 xmlns="http://www.123456768.com/technology">
<rptHdr>
<exchNam>MyXML</exchNam>
<envText>P</envText>
<rptCod>pp010</rptCod>
<rptNam>Daily Stock</rptNam>
<membLglNam>CompanyA</membLglNam>
<rptPrntEffDat>2015-04-14</rptPrntEffDat>
<rptPrntRunDat>2015-04-14</rptPrntRunDat>
</rptHdr>
<pp010Grp>
<pp0510KeyGrp>
<membClgIdCod>HBGKP</membClgIdCod>
</pp0510KeyGrp>
<pp010Grp1>
<pp010KeyGrp1>
<membExchIdCod>JBGJG</membExchIdCod>
</pp010KeyGrp1>
<pp010Grp2>
<pp010KeyGrp2>
<currTypCod>CHF</currTypCod>
</pp010KeyGrp2>
<pp010Grp3>
<pp010KeyGrp3>
<acctTypGrp>PP</acctTypGrp>
</pp010KeyGrp3>
<pp010Rec>
    <mgnGrpCod>     </mgnGrpCod>
    <mgnClsCod>CSLN </mgnClsCod>
    <mgnPremiumAmnt>+222926.00</mgnPremiumAmnt>
    <mgnLiqDlvAmnt>+0.00</mgnLiqDlvAmnt>
    <mgnSprdAmnt>+0.00</mgnSprdAmnt>
    <mgnAddlAmnt>+89349.30</mgnAddlAmnt>
    <unadjMgnReq>+312275.30</unadjMgnReq>
</pp010Rec>
<pp010Rec>
    <mgnGrpCod>     </mgnGrpCod>
    <mgnClsCod>CSLM </mgnClsCod>
    <mgnPremiumAmnt>+55112.00</mgnPremiumAmnt>
    <mgnLiqDlvAmnt>+0.00</mgnLiqDlvAmnt>
    <mgnSprdAmnt>+0.00</mgnSprdAmnt>
    <mgnAddlAmnt>+30854.40</mgnAddlAmnt>
    <unadjMgnReq>+85966.40</unadjMgnReq>
</pp010Rec>

</pp010Grp3>
</pp010Grp2>
</pp010Grp1>
</pp010Grp>

</pp010>
```

So you can run

```
public class MarginRep
    {
        public string mgnGrpCod { get; set; }
        public string mgnClsCod { get; set; }
        public string mgnPremiumAmnt { get; set; }
        public string mgnLiqDlvAmnt { get; set; }
        public string mgnSprdAmnt { get; set; }
        public string mgnAddlAmnt { get; set; }
        public string unadjMgnReq { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}\n{6}",
             mgnGrpCod, mgnClsCod, mgnPremiumAmnt, mgnLiqDlvAmnt, mgnSprdAmnt,
             mgnAddlAmnt, unadjMgnReq);
        }
    }

    var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("1.xml");
    XNamespace xn = xmlDoc.Root.Name.Namespace;
    IEnumerable<MarginRep> myMarginRep = xmlDoc.Root.Descendants(xn + "pp010Rec")
    .Select(c => new MarginRep()
        {
            mgnGrpCod = c.Element(xn + "mgnGrpCod").Value,
            mgnClsCod = c.Element(xn + "mgnClsCod").Value,
            mgnPremiumAmnt = c.Element(xn + "mgnPremiumAmnt").Value,
            mgnLiqDlvAmnt = c.Element(xn + "mgnLiqDlvAmnt").Value,
            mgnSprdAmnt = c.Element(xn + "mgnSprdAmnt").Value,
            mgnAddlAmnt = c.Element(xn + "mgnAddlAmnt").Value,
            unadjMgnReq = c.Element(xn + "unadjMgnReq").Value
        });
    foreach (var x in myMarginRep)
        Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Print:

```
CSLN
+222926.00
+0.00
+0.00
+89349.30
+312275.30

CSLM
+55112.00
+0.00
+0.00
+30854.40
+85966.40
```

**Update:**
Link: http://rextester.com/UFLPQ70590

Answer (score 1):

You do need to do what JAT said in his post about changing the attributes to elements, but that isn't the reason why your list is not being created from the XML.  It's the namespace ("xmlns="http://www.123456768.com/technology") that is giving you trouble.   I'm not sure what your XML file is trying to accomplish by having it, but if you remove it and do what JAT recommended your IEnumerable will start to be populated.

For more information about namespaces, you can check out this link from w3:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Comment: Cool. tried it, got the following error "There are multiple root elements. Line 11, position 2." will have a read of the link.

Comment: That's an issue with the actual XML file.   I had to remove some pieces from your first sample as the missing pieces you didn't include.   Once you get that error fixed this should get the list you want.   This is all I have for the XML file on my end where it is working without the namespace:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pp010>
<pp010Rec>
    <mgnGrpCod>     </mgnGrpCod>
    <mgnClsCod>CSLN </mgnClsCod>
    <mgnPremiumAmnt>+222926.00</mgnPremiumAmnt>
    <mgnLiqDlvAmnt>+0.00</mgnLiqDlvAmnt>
    <mgnSprdAmnt>+0.00</mgnSprdAmnt>
    <mgnAddlAmnt>+89349.30</mgnAddlAmnt>
    <unadjMgnReq>+312275.30</unadjMgnReq>
</pp010Rec>
</pp010>

Comment: Had to remove the second "pp010Rec" as SO has a character limit on comments apparently.